# How to pass control.ClientId to an OnClick function in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to turn on/off various `RequiredFieldValidator` controls when checkboxes are checked/unchecked, based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132837/asp-net-make-a-textbox-required-if-a-checkbox-is-checked). But rather than having a separate js function for each checkbox I want to pass in the ClientID of the input to validate, something like this (only one INPUT here but you can see once it's working I can add more INPUTs without more js):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubjectRequired" runat="server" 
    OnClick="updateValidator('<%= rfvSubject.ClientID %>');" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSubject" ControlToValidate="txtSubject" 
    ErrorMessage="You must enter a subject." runat="server" />

 <script>
 function updateValidator(inputId) {
      var enableValidator = !event.srcElement.checked;
      var theInput = document.getElementById(inputId);
      ValidatorEnable(theInput, enableValidator);
 }
 </script>
```

Currently that scriptlet `txtSubject.ClientID` isn't evaluated, just output directly. I'm sure this is simple but I just don't know the appropriate syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about adding it via the codebehind (or a script section):

```
checkSubjectRequired.Attributes.Add("onclick", "updateValidator(" + 
  txtSubject.ClientID + ")");
```

[This explaination of ClientID](http://edgewaters.blogspot.com/2007/12/defaultbutton-defaultfocus-and-uniqueid.html) may be helpful.

Comment: Yeah, seems like it's just not possible to do in the aspx file unless it's done in javascript. I ended up doing it in javascript, e.g.: `<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubjectRequired" runat="server" OnClick="updateValidator('rfvSubject');" />` then in a SCRIPT section: `function updateValidator(rfvName) { var inputMap = { "rfvSubject": "<%= rfvSubject.ClientId %>", ... more entries }; var rfvId = inputMap[rfvName]; ... do stuff with rfvId ...`. Yes, it's a bit gross but for some reason I didn't want codebehind adding the onclick.

Answer (score 0):

This is because; ASP.NET parser can not parse server tag "<% =  %>" for a server side control (i.e. control made as runat='server'). 
Use the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" /> 
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubjectRequired" runat="server"  
    OnClick="updateValidator('<%#txtSubject.ClientID %>');" /> 
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSubject" ControlToValidate="txtSubject"  
    ErrorMessage="You must enter a subject." runat="server" /> 

 <script> 
 function updateValidator(inputId) { 
      var enableValidator = !event.srcElement.checked; 
      var theInput = document.getElementById(inputId); 
      ValidatorEnable(theInput, enableValidator); 
 } 
 </script>
```

Comment: hmmm... so just replace `<%=` with `<%#`? In the output page that just resolves to `onclick="updateValidator('<%#txtSubject.ClientID %>');"`, i.e. same problem.

Comment: Try to escape the quotes: onclick="updateValidator('" + <%#txtSubject.ClientID %> + "');"

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" /> 
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSubjectRequired" runat="server"  
    OnClientClick="updateValidator(this.id);" /> 
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSubject" ControlToValidate="txtSubject"  
    ErrorMessage="You must enter a subject." runat="server" /> 

 <script> 
 function updateValidator(inputId) { 
      var enableValidator = !event.srcElement.checked; 
      var theInput = document.getElementById(inputId); 
      ValidatorEnable(theInput, enableValidator); 
 } 
 </script>
```

Comment: But that passes the id of the checkbox when I want the textbox control.

Comment: Doesn't your example try to pass the `ClientID` of the validator "`OnClick="updateValidator('<%= rfvSubject.ClientID %>');"`"

Comment: You're right - my mistake, I want the validator control rather than the textbox or the checkbox.