# Javascript validation for checkboxlist&textbox together

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Please help with below code, only text box validation works.Check box Validation doesn't work.
If I place only checkboxlist validation in my code it works, but both textbox and check box list together doesn't work.

```
function Validate() {
        var Branches = 3
        var CHK = document.getElementById("<%=CheckBoxList1.ClientID%>");
        var checkbox = CHK.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var counter = 0;
        var CollegeName = document.getElementById('<%=txtCollegeName.ClientID %>').value;
        var Location = document.getElementById('<%=txtLocation.ClientID %>').value;
            if (CollegeName == "")
            {
                alert("Please Enter College Name");
                return false;
            }
            if (Location == "")
            {
                alert("Please Enter Location");
                return false;
            }
    for (var i = 0; i < checkbox.length; i++) {
        if (checkbox[i].checked) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (atLeast > counter) {
        alert("Please select atleast " + Branches + " Branches");
        return false;
    }              
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132837/asp-net-make-a-textbox-required-if-a-checkbox-is-checked

Comment: what do you get in `atLeast` and `counter` variable?

Comment: Apologies the code was correct alteast must have been replaced with Branches Variable.I forgot that. I am using counter variable to compare with Branches variable

Comment: Alteast Varable is used instead of Branches Variable at 'if (atLeast > counter)'.